# How to change an hidden inputs value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a hidden inputs value when I push on a button. Here's what I'm doing.

My hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" value="action" id="action" />
```

My buttons

```
<INPUT name=submit value=~#SUBMIT~ type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="submitDatum">
<INPUT name=delete value=~#DELETE~ type="button" id="btnDelete" class="submitDatum">
```

My javascript

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $('#action').val('submit');
});

$("#btnDelete").click(function() {
    $('#action').val('delete');
});
```

Could anybody help?

kind regards

Comment: Code looks good. Whats is wrong with it?

Comment: Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmhdj/6/ click on submit and you will get alert.

Comment: I should better quote names and values in the markup. And the code will be perfect.

Comment: strange, because when I click submit and I am goind to look in the page source, the value is still action.

Comment: @StefGeelen Page source does not display all dynamic changes of your page. Use debuggers (like Firebug in FF) and console for that.

Comment: sometimes browser don't show the value of hidden field when it updated in such a way? you could use `alert($('#action').val());` after change statement

Comment: your code works as expected on jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/3U4Ld/

Comment: ya.........its strange behaviour but when u console it (console.log($('#action').val());)  after setting value in field , u will get new value.

Comment: oké in firebug it is oké ;) thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <INPUT name=submit onclick="change_value('btnSubmit','submit')" value=~#SUBMIT~ type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="submitDatum">
 <INPUT name=delete onclick="change_value('btnDelete','delete')"  value=~#DELETE~ type="button" id="btnDelete" class="submitDatum">

 function change_value(htmlid,value_change) {
    $('#'+htmlid).val(value_change);   
}
```

try this